# Python global variable is not being accessed in function

Tags: python, multithreading, list, variables, global

This is my python module that is being ran as two threads in main. One thread runs `monitor_wind()` which adds to `wind_count` every spin and another thread runs `calculate_speed()` to get wind in mph from the count, and add it to a list that is later averaged for average wind in mph.

My problem is that `calculate_speed()` doesn't seem to be accessing the global variable `wind_count`, it is always 0 even when `monitor_wind()` is adding to. But the changes it makes to `wind_list` can be seen in the `globals()` list.

How can I get it to access the global variable?

```py
from gpiozero import Button
import math
from time import sleep

wind_sensor = Button(6)
wind_count = 0
wind_list = []

def calculate_speed():
    while True:
        global wind_list, wind_count
        print(wind_count)
        radius_cm = 9.0
        cm_in_mile = 160934.4
        circumference_cm = (2 * math.pi) * radius_cm
        rotations = wind_count / 2.0
        dist_miles = (circumference_cm * rotations) / cm_in_mile
        speed = dist_miles / 5 # Divide distance by time, 5 seconds
        print(speed)
        wind_list.append(speed)
        wind_count = 0 # Reset wind count
        sleep(5)

def spin():
    global wind_count
    wind_count += 1

def monitor_wind():
    wind_sensor.when_pressed = spin
```

Comment: Do you ever call `monitor_wind`? The simple explanation is that `spin` isn't being called, which means that the callback is never being registered, or the callback isn't being called. Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Yes spin is being called. It started as a thread in main.py. I have tested it by adding print statements to `monitor_wind` and watching `wind_count` increment.

Comment: `from wspeed import monitor_wind, calculate_speed, wind_avg, wind_list
th_wmonitor = th.Thread(target=monitor_wind, daemon=True)
th_wspeed = th.Thread(target=calculate_speed, daemon=True)
th_wspeed.start(); th_wmonitor.start()`

Comment: `monitor_wind` looks like it doesn't actually run the `spin` function, it just binds `spin` to your `wind_sensor` button. Is there a reason you don't just bind it once at the start? It looks like if you do that, `spin` is still run every time the button is pressed.

Comment: This portion of my program is/was actually working correctly. I thought the variable wasn't being accessed because the average was coming out to 0.0 when there were readings. This was because I was including the 0.0 wind readings in the average, which after rounding made the result 0 wind average. I've since added an if statement to execute `calculate_speed` if `wind_count` is not 0

Comment: Good point, @BatWannabe. I completely missed that because I immediately tried replacing gpio stuff with random generation. It also made me realize that my solution is unnecessarily complicated because calculat_speed can be run from main. Time for another update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this does not appear to be an issue with your use of globals, though I would discourage using globals, and instead make a class `WindMonitor`. You should also use a lock if you are accessing a variable from multiple threads.

Try this out (I had to call spin on random time intervals because I don't have gpios on my device).

`wspeed.py`

```python
# from gpiozero import Button
import math
import random
import threading
from time import sleep

DEFAULT_WIND_SENSOR = None; # Button(6)

class WindMonitor:
    def __init__(self, button=DEFAULT_WIND_SENSOR):
        self.wind_count = 0
        self.wind_list = []
        self.button = button
        self.wind_count_lock = threading.Lock()
    
    def calculate_speed(self, stop_event):
        while True:
            with self.wind_count_lock:
                print(self.wind_count)
                radius_cm = 9.0
                cm_in_mile = 160934.4
                circumference_cm = (2 * math.pi) * radius_cm
                rotations = self.wind_count / 2.0
                dist_miles = (circumference_cm * rotations) / cm_in_mile
                speed = dist_miles / 5 # Divide distance by time, 5 seconds
                print(speed)
                self.wind_list.append(speed)
                self.wind_count = 0 # Reset wind count
            if stop_event.wait(5):
                return
    
    def spin(self):
        with self.wind_count_lock:
            self.wind_count += 1

    def monitor_wind(self):
        # self.button.when_pressed = self.spin
        while True:
            sleep(float(random.randint(1, 10)) / 10)
            self.spin()
```

`__main__.py`

```
import threading as th
import time
from wspeed import WindMonitor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    monitor = WindMonitor()
    stop_event = th.Event()
    th_wmonitor = th.Thread(target=monitor.monitor_wind, daemon=True)
    th_wspeed = th.Thread(target=monitor.calculate_speed, args=[stop_event], daemon=True)
    try:
        th_wspeed.start()
        th_wmonitor.start()
        while True: time.sleep(100)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        stop_event.set()
```

**Edit: Explaining stop event**

All of your threads loop forever (main thread, `th_wmonitor`, and `th_wspeed`).
You want the program to exit when the main terminates.

When python exits, it waits for all non-daemonic threads to terminate, so you did the right thing by making them daemonic. The problem is that python will only exit when there is a **single** remaining daemonic thread. Because both daemonic threads loop infinitely, you need a way to tell one (or both) of them to when the program exits.

The simplest way of achieving this is to use a `threading.Event` object. An `Event` is a simple way of communicating between threads. It's basically a flag that you set in one thread and check in another. By having an exception in main, you can set the `stop_event` instance of `threading.Event`. This lets any thread with access to `stop_event` that the main thread has exited, and other threads may terminate when they are ready to terminate.

The `th_wspeed` needs to terminate at a specific time because you don't want to terminate in the middle of a print statement. For that reason, I made `th_wspeed` the one to check `stop_event`. When `th_wspeed` sees `stop_event` has been set, it returns, thus terminating one of the two daemonic threads. At that point, because python sees that only one daemonic thread remains, it will force that thread to terminate, and the program exits.

Without the stop event, the program would not terminate when you, for example, press CTRL+C.

Comment: Thank you! I know I need to be using classes, especially now that I have several other modules with global variables and threads for other sensors. I just wasn't sure about the __init__ but it looks like it's a constructor. I'm reading the official class documentation to get more familiar.
Can you explain what the stop event is, and how it's working in your example?

Comment: Too long to put in a comment. Updated the answer with a response.

Comment: Forgot to mention that the reason you should `th_wmoniter` as a daemonic thread is that you do not want it to terminate immediately. You want it to terminate after `th_wspeed` so your last speed printed is accurate you could a spin if `th_wmonitor` terminates before `th_wspeed`.

Comment: Updated again. Previously, `th_wspeed` would wait as much as 5 seconds before terminating once `stop_event` was set. It will now terminate immediately after `stop_event` is set.